# How to calculate total days between start date & end date in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

I am using `DatePicker` control in SAPUI5, I want to calculate total days between `selected` start date and end date.

```js
var startDate = this.getView().byId("DP-FromDate").getValue();
var endDate = this.getView().byId("DP-ToDate").getValue();
var sDate = new Date(startDate);
var eDate = new Date(endDate);

var diff = Math.abs(sDate.getTime() - eDate.getTime());
var diffD = Math.ceil(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
alert(diffD);
```

I am getting `sdate & eDate` are `Invalid dates` Error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `getDateValue` method instead of `getValue`.

[`getDateValue`](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.DatePicker.html#getDateValue) returns date as JavaScript Date object.
So, there will be no need to convert it to date format.

Then, your code would be:

```js
var startDate = this.getView().byId("DP-FromDate").getDateValue();
var endDate = this.getView().byId("DP-ToDate").getDateValue();  
var diff = Math.abs(startDate.getTime() - endDate.getTime());
var diffD = Math.ceil(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)); 
alert(diffD);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `getValue` method of `sap.m.DatePicker` returns a formatted and localized date string(!), e.g. 'May 12th 2015', which will not necessarily work as an input parameter for the `Date` constructor.

Fortunately you don't have to convert anything: You just need to use the method [getDateValue](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.DatePicker.html#getDateValue). It will return a ready-to-use `Date` object.